# Are there any critical points to consider regarding the externally owned account (EOA) that deployed the Safe contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am planning to deploy [the Safe contract](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts) on a custom network using [the Deterministic Deployment Proxy](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory) using my personal wallet.

Assuming that I have high hopes for the Safe app to perform well on the custom network, are there any potential issues or concerns that I should be mindful of? For instance, would it be a problem if I were to lose my personal wallet? Could the custom network team ask for my private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When utilizing the Deterministic Deployment Proxy, deploying the contract using your personal wallet is not an option. Instead, the process requires a presigned transaction that employs the Safe team wallet.